# How to create location/ when it doesn't exist in applicationHost.config with Powershell and IISAdministration module

Tags: powershell, iis

Any ideas how to add a new  element to the root of the applicationHost.config using IISAdministration module?

I'd cobbled together the current code (edited for brevity) to bootstrap a new site in IIS 10.

```
Import-Module IISAdministration
$Manager = Get-IISServerManager
$Name = "my.sitedomain.foo"
$Config = $Manager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration()
$Config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/dynamicIpSecurity",$Name)
$DIPSecurity = $Config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/dynamicIpSecurity",$Name)
if($DIPSecurity -ne $null){
    $DIPSecurity.GetChildElement("denyByRequest") | %{
        $_.SetAttributeValue("enabled",$true)
        $_.SetAttributeValue("maxRequests",20)
        $_.SetAttributeValue("requestIntervalInMilliseconds",200)
    }            
}
```

When the dynamicIpSecurity element has been modified via IIS Manager then the xml gets added to the config file. Out-of-the-box, however, my IIS applicationHost.config does not have a `<location>` child element for the site.

The intention is to check if the location element exists and if not, add something like the following

```
<location path="my.sitedomain.foo">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <dynamicIpSecurity>
                <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" />
                <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" />
            </dynamicIpSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Many thanks,
James

Comment: Generally speaking, you cannot. It would be IIS API who decides where to save the settings and whether location tags are needed. In your case if you want to manage a site, the code above is wrong (you should not call `GetApplicationHost...`.

Comment: Thanks @Lexi Li  - I thought that the dynamicIpSecurity collection was one of a few odd cases that had to be modified via the applicationHost.

Comment: There is no “odd”. Sections have different overriding modes, and ones like `dynamicSecurity` by default would be only overridden in `applicationHost.config` and typically via location tags. If you spare more time on IIS configuration system, then such would be obvious.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for comments they led me down the right path of investigation. I'm very new to IIS Administration and have a lot still to learn about it. Thanks again for getting me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

My question was phrased poorly. Really, I should have asked "How do I configure dynamicIpSecurity for a specific site using IISAdministration powershell module?".

Due to my limited knowledge of IISAdministration and Microsoft.Web.Administration, my attention was focused on the wrong hurdle. The solution to the correct question came re-reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/scripting/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration#set-configuration-in-site-root-webconfig (thanks to Lex Li for shifting my thinking).

By using `ServiceManager.GetWebConfiguration("name.ofyour.site")` instead of using `ServiceManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration()` you get the configuration object for the specified website which includes all configuration elements regardless of the file where that configuration is actually written to.